# How can I restrict access to the php file on server to Java app only?

Tags: java, php, database, authorization, security

I have a Java application that sends user score to the mysql table. When the user is done, Java app accesses the .php file on server and the .php server performs a query on the database (inserting score).

I am concerned about the (in)security of this method. I mean, if someone finds out the direct url to the .php on a server, they can produce a lot of mess in the dabase. Can you advise how I could prevent the .php from executing the query other than accessed by the Java app?

edit: The problem is that Java application is NOT run on the server, it's run on the user computer using Java Web Launcher platform. So it's not an applet...

Comment: Just a question that might solve your problem by avoiding it altogether: Why don't you run the database query from your Java application?

Comment: I suggest you set up the correct permissions for the user that the Java app is run as. I assume you're using Linux?

Comment: An obvious question, is the Java application running on the same server as the php server?

Comment: The problem is that Java application is NOT runnig on the server, it's running on the user computer using Java Web Launcher platform. So it's not an applet...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is conceptual. You should never be sure that users can't find out the real address (security by obscurity). You could use SSL, still this is no means against a good guess.

Since the Java program is run on the client side, a .htaccess restricting access to a certain IP is also not an option.

My suggestion is to create a separate user in mysql, grant this user access only to necessary tables and perform the database queries on behalf of this user directly in Java. This way all data is encrypted (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ssl-connections.html) and no URL/access point is exposed. Of course it means your MySQL server must be reachable from outside which poses a risk, too. You should have a good root password!